# How to handle Pubnub APNS notification

Tags: swift, cocoapods, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I am using Pubnub in my IOS app for chatting , where I am able to create a channel and do all the messaging.
However if I have my app in background , and when a user sends a message I don't get any push notification for that.

I have configured My APNS id's in push notification and push notification is also enabled there.

For publish message I am using following method

```
let metadata : [String : Any] = ["date" : "","message" : messageText,"id" : 1, "sender" : 1, "receiver" : 12]
 let payloads : [String : Any]  = ["aps" : ["alert": ["body":"This is the content of my push notification","title":"Push Notification Title"]],"pn_debug": true,
        "pn_push" : [["push_type" : "alert","auth_method" : "token",
        "targets": ["environment" : "development", " topic" : "com.myapp.com"],
        "version" : "v2"]]]
   

 self.pubnub.publish(["data" : metadata], toChannel: self.connectionName, mobilePushPayload:payloads ) { (status) in
    if let error = status.error {
      print("error",error)
    } else {
        print("status.........",status)
    }
   }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Wnjit, Please edit your question and show some of the code you used

Comment: Your message payload does not include the required format for PubNub nor for APNs. See these docs for more details: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/messages/push/send#sending-push-notifications  If you have more questions, please add comments here or send full details to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and add a link to this SO post so we can answer back her.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @CraigConover. 

please check the edited question. Still its not working for me.

Comment: Notification worked for the same channel when I send it from pubnub debug console . But not from app side code.

Comment: This just means that message you are sending has a different payload/format. I would send this to PubNub Support with full details, logs, payloads, etc and we can post the answer back on this link.

Comment: @WinjitDevNasik - just wondering if you submitted to PN Support and if you have a solution to this issue?